# Javascript Undefined Check Shorthand

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to default a javascript value if something in an object with 3+ depth is undefined.  For instance, something like this:

```js
var finalData = {};
const data = {};
finalData.transactions = data.b.transactions || [];
```

instead of:

```js
var finalData = {};
const data = {};
if (data.b)
    finalData.transactions = data.b.transactions || [];
else
    finalData.transactions = [];
```

The problem with the first line is it will fail with an undefined access issue if data does not have a child named b.

Comment: The most I can think of is using a ternary comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining && and ||:

```
finalData.transactions = (data && data.b && data.b.transactions) || [];
```

Comment: this will fail if `data.b.transactions ` is a `boolean` type and the value of `transactions ` is false

Comment: As @Akbarkhan pointed out, this will fail if data.b.transactions is a `boolean`.
The following falsey values will also make this fail: `0` or `""`.  More accurate would be `data && data.b && data.b.transactions !== undefined && data.b.transactions || []`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```js
var finalData = {};
const data = {};
finalData.transactions = data.b && data.b.transactions || [];
```